# Set tooltip in date format Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi  i am usng  a highchart  where i wbnt to set tooltip value in specific format,

i have  categories and series in folloing format:

```
json message{"Categoires":["2015-11-09","2015-11-08""2015-11-15"],"Series":[2,0,2]}
```

here i  am using categories value to set  in tooltip where i am geting in 
`"2015-11-09"` format.

and i want to set in this for amt:

```
Wednesday, Nov 11, 2015
```

any one can helo le please  help  i am usin high chart first time.

Updated code

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we set the date format in tooltip

```
tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
        shared: true
    }
```

And these are the various date formats we can use

```
millisecond:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L",
second:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S",
minute:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M",
hour:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M",
day:"%A, %b %e, %Y",
week:"Week from %A, %b %e, %Y",
month:"%B %Y",
year:"%Y"
```

For reference here is an example :

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
        spacingRight: 20
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        showFirstLabel: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true,
        categories: dateAndTimeArray,
        tickInterval: 10,
        labels: {
            rotation: 0.1,
            align: 'left',
            step: 10,
            enabled: true
        },
        style: {
            fontSize: '8px'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Measurement value'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            shadow: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            //  threshold: null
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Value',
        data: chartData,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: I would recommend you to go through this simple example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/). If you could create a jsfiddle, i can help you through.